# Changing MUI Switch component colors

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm using switch component from MUI, I want to toggle the styling between two colors

```html
<Switch
  color={dataType === "expenses" ? "error" : "secondary"}
  onChange={handleOnSwitch}
  checked={dataType === "expenses"}
/>
```

i can't find what is the specific props i should pass to customize the offSwitch color, in the documentations there is only props to the checked case, i want to change the switch color while unchecked to something other than the default gray.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: FYI, you could memoize the conditional e.g. `const isChecked = useMemo(() => dataType === "expenses", [dataType])` and then use is like `color={isChecked ? "error" : "secondary"}` and `checked={isChecked}`

Answer (score 0):

Here I am writing a sample code for you. You can get the look you want by changing the styled codes here.

```
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel/FormControlLabel';

export default function BasicSwitches() {
  const MaterialUISwitch = styled(Switch)(() => ({
    width: 62,
    height: 34,
    padding: 7,
    '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase': {
      margin: 1,
      padding: 0,
      transform: 'translateX(6px)',
      '&.Mui-checked': {
        color: '#fff',
        transform: 'translateX(22px)',
        '& + .MuiSwitch-track': {
          opacity: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        },
      },
    },
    '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      width: 32,
      height: 32,
      '&::before': {
        content: "''",
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
      },
    },
    '& .MuiSwitch-track': {
      opacity: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderRadius: 20 / 2,
    },
  }));
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<MaterialUISwitch sx={{ m: 1 }} defaultChecked />}
        label="MUI switch"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use style props like that

```
<FormControl required>
  <FormLabel id="category-status" className={classes.inputLabel}>
    Status
  </FormLabel>
  <FormControlLabel
    control={(
      <Switch
        checked={formData?.Status}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="Status"
        inputRef={statusRef}
        onKeyDown={(e) => handleFormEnterKey(e, IconURL)}
        style={{ color: formData?.Status === true ? '#33cf4d' : 'gray' }}
      />
    )}
   />
</FormControl>
```